# Recreating database: rake tasks using the db end up loading models/other files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake

I have a lot of spots in my code that actually call activerecord finders.  For example, in a Blog engine, I might have a table of `tags` that correspond to an activerecord model `Tag`.  Suppose, for some reason, that I want special logic to happen if a post is created with a tag where `tag.description == 'humor'`.  Then I might have a method in the model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.humor_tag
    find_by_description('humor')
  end

end
```

Whether or not this is poor design, it causes insane amounts of problems for me when using rake commands to build a database.  Say that later on, I've finished my development and I want to deploy to production.  So I take the dumped schema.rb file, and then I want to load a new database structure from that schema.rb, or alternatively, just run my migrations to create a production database.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

The problem is that, in the production environment, the rake command seems to load every model.  When it tries to load the `Tag#humor_tag` method, it throws an error that stops the process:

```
rake aborted!
Table 'production_database.tags' doesn't exist
```

Well of course it doesn't exist, it hasn't been created yet!  I've googled around and people seem to solve this problem by either cloning the database in SQL or moving around their code just so they can run the rake task.

What are you supposed to do?  It seems like there might be some configuration somewhere to let you tell rake to freaking ignore calls to database tables before any tables are created.

Comment: What do you have in your initializers? ActiveAdmin perhaps?

Comment: No ActiveAdmin, though I do have a few initializers.  I'd rather not list them all here, but that's a good place for me to look.  Is there anything I should look for in them?  I do use devise which has some active_record adapter: `require 'devise/orm/active_record'`.

Comment: I've heard of people having this problem with ActiveAdmin because it tries to grok the database structure in an initializer. Check your initializers for anything that touches your models. Most of the Rake stuff wants to crank up all the Rails stuff for the `:environment` prerequisite so your initializers can't touch the database or you'll get stuck in a dependency loop and make everyone sad.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing queries by class methods with scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

and if you have an initializer that is causing the models to load, use a proc in the scope definition, such as

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, Proc.new { where(:published => true) }
end
```

to prevent the scope from running at initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely satisfied with this answer, but if anyone gets to this question and has a similar problem, this may be helpful.  In order to move over a database in a situation where you would usually `rake db:schema:load` or just create it and run the migrations, you can alternatively load the database from SQL (or presumably other database technologies).

```
rake db:structure:dump
```

That command will dump the structure of the database into a file that will then be able to recreate it.  For me, it created a file `db/development_dump.sql`, that contained calls to create all of the tables and indices, but didn't copy any of the data like on a normal sql dump.  Then, I moved that file to my production database, and ran it:

```
mysql prod_database < development_dump.sql
```

This doesn't answer the question at hand, but it may be relevant for someone facing a similar problem.